# Register user in Strapi.io application using GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, mutation

I'm connecting to my app and querying with graphql works fine (I'm using Apollo client).  On the strapi development graphql playground, I can successfully register a user.  However, when I try to implement the same mutation in react, I'm getting a 400 error.

Here's my hook:

```
//useRegister.js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {gql, useMutation} from "@apollo/client";

const REGISTER=gql`
    mutation Register($input: UsersPermissionsRegisterInput!) {
      register(input: $input) {
        jwt
        user {
          id
          username
          email
          role
        }
      }
    }
`

const useRegister = () => {
    const [callMutation, {loading, data, error}] = useMutation(REGISTER);

    const register = async (email, password) => {
        const result = await callMutation({
            variables: {
                input: {
                    email,
                    password,
                    username: email
                }
            }
        });
        console.log('useRegister.register.result', result);
    }

    return [register, data, loading, error];
}

export default useRegister
```

Here's the code in my form which calls it:

```
...
    const [register, response, loading, error] = useRegister();
...
useEffect(() => {
        if(response) {
            console.log('Register.useEffect.response', response);
            //saving user implemented here
        }
    }, [response])
...
const handleOnSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            await register(form.email, form.password);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('err', err);
        }
    }
```

The catch part of the try/catch is being invoked.

Comment: you should show log result and check NETWORK response details ... auth reasons? ... BTW, this hook is almost useless, unmanageable (hardcoded args), useState unnecessary (use `data` from `useQuery`) ... better to keep query outside of code, in .graphql file (gql tag loader)

Comment: Thanks - I had actually removed the unnecessary useState and will check the server's logs.

Comment: The network response is just a 400 error.

Comment: should contain explanation, too ... check request - values not passed? console.log `register` args?

Comment: turns out it was the return value in the graphql that was causing the problem.